# Rename mapped drive(Network Drive ) with batch script

Tags: batch-file, resources

I created below `.bat` file but it is not renaming network drive lable `T:`newdrive saying parameter not compatible.
Please, any help.

```
@echo off
:REM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:REM
:REM Batch file for establishing a WebDAV connection and bind it to a drive
:REM letter (non-persistent).
:REM
:REM Please adopt WEBDAV_HOST and WEBDAV_USER to your needs as well as the
:REM default password. You also might want to adopt the default drive the
:REM WebDAV connection should be bound to.
:REM
:REM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

:REM ~~~~~~~~~~
:REM PARAMETERS
:REM ~~~~~~~~~~

set WEBDAV_HOST=https://box.kph/remote.php/webdav
set WEBDAV_USER=abc

:REM Use "*" to let "net use" ask you for the password. You might
:REM change this to the real password but mind that this is a security risk.
set WEBDAV_PASSWORD=xyz

set DRIVE=T:
if exist %DRIVE% (
  echo Drive %DRIVE% already in use. Choosing the next free one...
  set DRIVE=*
)

:REM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:REM Establish Connection
:REM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

echo Establishing connection to "%WEBDAV_HOST%" for "%WEBDAV_USER%"...
echo.
net use "%DRIVE%" "%WEBDAV_HOST%" /User:"%WEBDAV_USER%" "%WEBDAV_PASSWORD%" /persistent:no
if not errorlevel 1 (
  echo.
  net use
)
:END
label T: newdrive
pause
```

Comment: the `label` command doesn't give you a "convenient name" for the drive but changes the volume label itself. Network drives don't have a volume label. The name of the drive is defined on the server which hosts the volume.